# Custom tags in link_to helper

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to insert some tags inside link that was created using link_to helper
I want something like `<a href = "#">Somename <sometag></sometag></a>`
I tried to use

```
<%= link_to 'Somename',  {:action => 'somepath' }, :class => 'btn' do %>
<i class="icon-file icon-white"></i>
<%end%>
```

but it gave me some wierd result. How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using a block with `link_to`, the first argument should be the url/path. Whatever is inside the block will be inserted inside the `<a>` tags.

```
<%= link_to {:action => 'somepath' }, :class => 'btn' do %>
  <i class="icon-file icon-white"></i> Somename
<% end %>
```

Is probably closer to what you want.